# Sanitizing CSS in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, css, security

I want to allow the users of a web app that I'm building to write their own CSS in order to customize their profile page.

However I am aware of this opening up for many security risks, i e background: url('javascript:alert("Got your cookies! " + document.cookies').

Hence I am looking for a solution to sanitize the CSS while still allowing as much CSS functionality as possible for my users.

So my questions if anyone anyone knows of a gem or a plugin to handles this? I've googled my brains out already so any tips would be really appreciated!

Comment: just curious, how are you storing your CSS? in database or as a file for each user?

Comment: Wow.. crazy that you can execute javascript from CSS like that. No idea how to solve it though - sorry!

Comment: Shripad K: I'll store the CSS in the database.

zaius: Yup! Check out this page: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#css-injection

Answer (score 7):

Rails has a built-in css sanitizer

See http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize_css and its parent http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize

```
> ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize_css('background:#fff')
=> "background: #fff;" 
> ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize_css('javascript:alert("garr");')
=> ""
```

Comment: Ok, thank you! But as I understand it this method is only used to sanitize a style attribute on a HTML element. It can't be used to sanitize an entire stylesheet…?

Comment: It should be just the same - one line or a stack of lines... it won't matter.

Comment: It does not handle entire stylesheet.

Comment: `full_stylesheet.gsub(/\{([^}]*)\}/m){ '{' + ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize_css($1) + '}'; }` could be enough.

Answer (score 1):

There's also some code called css_file_sanitize: https://github.com/courtenay/css_file_sanitize

Comparing it to the Rails `sanitize` command I find that both use regular expressions to strip out undesirable portions of the CSS.

Here's the source for css_file_sanitize: https://github.com/courtenay/css_file_sanitize/blob/master/lib/css_sanitize.rb

Here's the source for Rails `sanitize`: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/vendor/html-scanner/html/sanitizer.rb